# Why there is no import.java.util.Scanner; in jdk1.7?

Tags: java

I started learning Java programming 2 days ago and then I started reading a tutorial that required Scanner class, when I realized that it just does not exist.

I looked in the left corner in rt.jar and resources.jar, but nothing.

I'm using JDK1.7.0_45, and I tried 1.6 as well, but it still does not appear.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You can't import `java.util` or you can't see the `Scanner.java` in `src.zip`? which one?

Comment: There is no such thing as `import.java.util.Scanner`. The class is `java.util.Scanner`. You can import it by specifying `import java.util.Scanner` outside your class definition.

Comment: does this even compile?

Answer (score 1):

Its available in `Java 7`

[Reference to Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Its not `import.java.util.Scanner`

its `import java.util.Scanner`